# How would you predict chemical reactions given arbitrary chemical compounds and spatial positions + velocity?

Tags: forces, computational-physics, physical-chemistry

Much of physics education focuses on equations of known possible reactions, how to balance them, how to predict the result if certain elements happen to react with each other.

What I don't see a lot of is an explanation of what chemical reactions are likely to happen in a complex system.

Assume I was building a physical simulation where I know the position/velocity of any number of elements or compounds. What would the process be to determine which chemical reactions are most likely to occur?

[image: example drawing of compounds in space]

Given my assumption:

1. Treat the collision of each atom as a sphere of varying size depending on the size of the type of atom's valence field (sphere collision is to reduce computational complexity).
2. Calculate magnetic attraction/repulsion between local atoms and manipulate the velocities accordingly.
3. If the valence fields of two atoms overlap (or are near each other?) due to attraction, electrons are exchanged, and other atoms that are the least magnetically attracted are either re-positioned or rejected from the compound depending on the magnetic forces and electron availability.
4. I assume "heat" based reactions can be derived from velocity of a collision?

Would this be a sufficient model to predict an arbitrary chemical reaction or non-reaction?

Comment: I think I've only seen probability distribution models (i.e., using transition amplitudes to switch from one state to another), rather than discrete-particle interaction models, when it comes to chemical reactions.